# Переопределение объекта и динамическая загрузка сборок

Tags: c#

Подскажите как мне лучше реализовать следующий функционал в библиотеке для парсинга MPEG TS потоков https://github.com/deimspb/TSParser

В моей либе есть стандартные дескрипторы, но я бы хотел чтобы пользователи этой либы имели возможность динамически подключать свои кастомные дескрипторы или переопределять созданные мной, без пересборки либы.
Весь функционал по созданию дескрипторов находиться в этом классе https://github.com/deimspb/TSParser/blob/master/TSParser/Descriptors/DescriptorFactory.cs
на 38-й строке есть метод `GetDescriptor` в нём как-то хотелось бы реализовать динамическое подключение сборки и создание/переопределение дескрипторов.

Изначально пришла в голову следующая идея:
добавить перед блоком switch:

```
internal static Descriptor GetDescriptor(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes, string descAllocation = "")
        {
            try
            {
                if(GetCustomDescriptor(bytes, out Descriptor descriptor)) return descriptor;

                switch (bytes[0])
                {
                    case 0x0A: return new Iso639LanguageDescriptor_0x0A(bytes);
                    case 0x56: return new TeletextDescriptor_0x56(bytes);
                    case 0x6A: return new AC3Descriptor_0x6A(bytes);
                    .......
private static bool GetCustomDescriptor(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes, out Descriptor descriptor)
        {
            descriptor = null;               
        // пока заглушка
        //Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("CustomDescriptors.dll");

        //Type tp = asm.GetType("CustomDescriptors.CustomDescriptor");

        //object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(tp);

        //MethodInfo method = tp.GetMethod("GetCustomDescriptor");
            return false;
        }
```

В файле CustomDescriptors.dll

```
public class CustomDescriptor
    {
        public bool GetCustomDescriptor(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes,out Descriptor descriptor)
        {
            descriptor = null;
            switch (bytes[0])
            {
                case 0x09: descriptor = new CaDescriptorCustom_0x09(bytes); return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Сам дескриптор:

```
public string? CasName { get; }
        public string? ProviderId { get; }
        public string? ServiceId { get; }
        public string? EKey { get; }
        public string? AKey { get; }
        public ushort CaSystemId { get; }
        public ushort CaPid { get; }
        public byte[] PrivateDateBytes { get; } = null!;
        public CaDescriptorCustom_0x09(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes) : base(bytes)
        {
            var pointer = 2;
            CaSystemId = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(bytes[pointer..]);
            pointer += 2;
            CaPid = BinaryPrimitives.ReadUInt16BigEndian(bytes[pointer..]);
            pointer += 2;
            PrivateDateBytes = new byte[DescriptorLength - pointer + 2];
            bytes.Slice(pointer, PrivateDateBytes.Length).CopyTo(PrivateDateBytes);

            if(CaSystemId == 0x**** || CaSystemId == 0x**** || CaSystemId == 0x****)
            {
                CasName = "****";
                ProviderId = GetPrividerId(PrivateDateBytes);
                EKey = GetEKey(PrivateDateBytes);
                AKey = GetAKey(PrivateDateBytes);
            }
        }
        public override string Print(int prefixLen)
        {
            string header = new string(' ', prefixLen);

            if (CasName == "****")
                return $"{header}Provider Id: {ProviderId}, CA pid: {CaPid}, private data: {BitConverter.ToString(PrivateDateBytes):X}\n";
            else
                return $"{header}CA system id: {CaSystemId}, CA pid: {CaPid}, private data: {BitConverter.ToString(PrivateDateBytes):X}\n";
        }
```

В либе изначально описан дескриптор с таким тегом. Нужно его заместить вот этим дескриптором. И как бы на этом у меня ступор. Как вытащить кастомный дескриптор со всеми полями и переопределениями.
Ранее с динамической загрузкой дело не имел. Подскажите как лучше реализовать этот функционал?

Ps Аналогичный функционал в коммерческой библиотеке от Dektec реализуется описанием дескриптора на xml и размещением этого файла в специальной папке
Пример xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Mp2TableTemplate xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Mp2TableTemplate.xsd">
    <DescriptorTempl tag = "162" name = "Test" standard = "mpeg">
        <DescriptorPresentation>
            <LongName str = "Test"/>
        </DescriptorPresentation>
        <DescriptorBody>
        <Field length = "8" name = "descriptor_tag" encoding = "uimsbf" semantics = "descriptor_tag">
            <FieldPresentation>
                <Prefix str = "descriptor_tag"/>
                <Format str = "0x%01X"/>
            </FieldPresentation>                
        </Field>
        <Field length = "8" name = "descriptors_length" encoding = "uimsbf"/>
            <Loop length_field = "descriptors_length">
                <LoopPresentation>
                    <LoopEmpty str = "channel"/>
                    <LoopEntry>
                        <EntryField entry_field = "program_id">
                            <FieldPresentation>
                                <Prefix str = "program_id"/>
                            </FieldPresentation>
                        </EntryField>
                    </LoopEntry>
                </LoopPresentation>
                <Body>
                <Field length = "16" name = "program_id" encoding = "bslbf">
                </Field>
                <Field length = "8" name = "program_type" encoding = "bslbf">
                        <FieldPresentation>
                            <Prefix str = "program_type(1-TV;2-Radio)"/>
                        </FieldPresentation>
                </Field>
                </Body>
            </Loop>
        </DescriptorBody>
    </DescriptorTempl>
</Mp2TableTemplate>
```

Похоже что внутри коммерческой либы на основе этого xml создаётся новый класс.

Pss Название полей в записях обусловлены стандартом (хотелось чтобы названия были такими же как в описании ETSI EN)

Comment: Так switch легко заменяется словарём. Создайте словарь `<byte, Type>`, и дело с концом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую